# Реализация одной страницы на React не в SPA приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть Админка сайта, написанная на обычном HTML/CSS/JS (jQuery) - т.е. это не SPA, рендер со стороны сервера в обычном HTML с последующим подключением JS (jQuery) к DOM-у на стороне клиента, как в старые-добрые времена.

Многие страницы Админки меня устраивают в таком исполнении (а именно в скорости разработки, где не требуются высокоинтерактивные интерфейсы), но вот появляется какая-нибудь страница, где нужно сделать что-то с высокоинтерактивными интерфейсами, например таблицу с деревом групп, фильтрацией, сортировками и другими вещами и я бы хотел реализовать эту таблицу на React компонентах.

Вот собственно вопрос, "можно ли будет / удобно ли будет / практикуется ли такой подход" реализовать только эту страницу на React компонентах (с Flux или Redux, Routing, может еще с чем-то, я просто еще плохо разбираюсь в React) с учетом того, что вся Админка не SPA? Т.е. насколько понимаю только для этой страницы мне нужно будет реализовать на стороне сервера REST API и взаимодействовать с ним на стороне клиента React компонентами, или может как-то иначе, а может вообще такое не практикуется и это плохое решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да такое решение возможно, и используется достаточно часто. По крайней мере я встречал несколько раз. Недостаток такого подхода это необходимость загружать дополнительные библиотеки javascript, собственно react, redux и так далее. Хотя если это дла админки, то не должно быть проблеммой.

Answer (score -3):

Это - очень частое решение, такое встречается сплошь и рядом. Да, разумеется, никто не может запретить вам так делать! И да, это достаточно удобный подход для встраивания мини-приложений в традиционный веб-сайт.

Из тонкостей реализации - сразу же выкиньте Flux, Redux или любой другой роутинг. Они нужны только в "настоящих" SPA, для одной страницы в многостраничном сайте они избыточны. Вам отлично подойдет чистый React.

Также позаботьтесь о правильном кешировании ваших скриптов на стороне браузера. Знаю, что совет банальный - но именно при подобном подходе (многостраничное приложение + тяжелая клиентская часть) оптимальная загрузка клиентских скриптов очень важна.

По поводу REST API - вопрос странный. Если вам нужно интерактивное взаимодействие с сервером - то API конечно же понадобится. Если не нужно - то не понадобится.

Пример когда API нужен - управление деревом пользователей и групп. Пример когда API не нужен - красивый просмотр того же дерева, без редактирования.

Comment: На счет выкинуть роутинг я могу еще согласится, но вот насчет выкинуть Redux(Flux) я бы поспорил. Redux и Flux это не роутинг.

Comment: @MikhailChibel оно там все равно избыточное. Хотя, согласен, могут и им найтись применения.

Comment: > з тонкостей реализации - сразу же выкиньте Flux, Redux или любой другой роутинг.

Да, только хотел сказать, что Flux и Redux - это не роутинг.. А по поводу роутинга, как без него обмениваться данными с сервером, через jQuery $.get(), $.post(), $.ajax()?

Comment: Flux и Redux не роутинг. Как следствие, их необходимость определяется исключительно логикой построения "мини-приложения" и обмена данными с сервером. Сразу рубить с плеча и отметать эти решения (без оценки их применимости) не имеет смысла.

Comment: @Александр а чем вас `$.post()` не устраивает? :) Нет, я понимаю, если страница сложная - все эти радости здорово помогут. Но если страница состоит из двух частей - формирователь запроса (дерево групп) и отображатель результатов (таблица) - то одного $.post() более чем достаточно.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov. Таблица с деревом групп будет не простая, будет создание/чтение/редактирование/удаление записей прямо в таблице. Ну да ладно, я вас понял.

Comment: Роутинг выкинуть надо, согласен. Но Flux/Redux не про роутинг, а про управление состоянием приложения. Если React тут вообще рассматривается в противовес jQuery (с доводами посерьёзнее "этожмодно"), значит, оно уже стало достаточно сложным.

Comment: Использовать в реакт компонентах `jquery` это сразу застрелится, иначе вы портите сам подход к написанию компонентов на реакте. А асинхронные методы писать на реакте легко, проблем не может возникать

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев речь идет не о всем jquery, а о его AJAX-хелперах. Их можно свободно использовать в любом проекте. И, насколько мне известно, в чистом React функций для AJAX-запросов нет - отсюда и jquery. Я вот только что погуглил по запросу "react flux ajax" - по трем ссылкам из 10 есть вызов `$.get` :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov реакт - это javascript. `jQuery` это обертка. Вы предлагаете грузить всю библиотеку (которая вообще не сдалась). Так же есть уже и такие методы как `fetch()`. От `jQuery` уже надо отходить, и не городить там, где он не нужен. vanilajs. А то что вы нагуглили, делают непонятные люди, которые сами использовали jquery всю свою жизнь, и не знают что такое `best practice`. Использовать `jquery` можно, но **нельзя** :)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев вопрос времени на разработку. У "старшего поколения" давно есть "свои" удобные обертки над XHR - остальным приходится пользоваться чем-то другим, ибо API XHR отвратителен. [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) не работает в IE, к сожалению.

Comment: @PavelMayorov дак для IE есть его же реализация, подключить не составляет проблем, там ~15 строк кода у метода

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев было бы неплохо, если бы вы привели ссылку на эту реализацию.

Comment: @PavelMayorov пожалуйста, полифил - https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: @PavelMayorov, речь не о том, что _именно использовать_ для получения состояния из компонентов React, а о том, что компоненты должны быть stateless. Именно отсюда растут ноги у решений вроде redux. Их основная цель отделить _состояние_ приложения от _визуального представления_ этого состояния. Перед тем, как категорично советовать от чего то отказаться, вам стоило бы ознакомиться с базовыми целями отметенных вами библиотек/подходов. tl;dr -- не вводите людей в заблуждение